# angular.js when to call ng-progress api methods

Tags: angularjs

I have this code

```
app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', 'ngProgress', '$timeout', function($location, $rootScope, ngProgress, $timeout) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
      console.log(ngProgress.status());
  ngProgress.complete();
  console.log(ngProgress.status());
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    console.log(ngProgress.status());
ngProgress.start();
console.log(ngProgress.status());

  });

}]);
```

It works, but loading bar shows just after the content of page is loaded, not when I click on link. So it looks like this:
1.I click link
2.I'm waiting 5 seconds
3.Page loaded;Progress bar shows;Progress bar ends

How to show progress bar just after I click on link and show progress?

Edit: I added into console current status(width) of bar. It's showing me 0,0,0,100 -> that's what I'm talking about, it's not working properly. It just shows and hides. (Even if page is loading 5 secons)

Comment: could you provider a plnkr to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I will have to copy much code..problem is that ngProgress.start() seems to wait for dom load

Comment: edit: I find the problem: for some reasons when start() method is called it's waiting for the content and then it start increasing, I have no idea why